# Capturing FORM input for session without submission

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to capture the value info for from a FORM without it being submitted and saving the info to a php session so it can be carried over to another page. This is what I have so far from basic knowledge and looking around the net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name="FirstName"]').change(function(){

    });
    $('input[name="Class"]').change(function(){

    });
    $('#Model').select(function() {
       var model=$('#Model').val();
     });
</script>

<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['FirstName'] = '';
$_SESSION['Class'] = '';
$_SESSION['Model'] = '';
?>

<form method='post' action='external.com/process.php' name='form101' id='form101' onChange="getModel">
<input type='text' name='FirstName' id='FirstName' value='' />
<input type='text' name='Class' id='Class' value='' />
  <select name="Model" id="Model">
    <option value="">------</option>
    <option value="Model 1">Model 1</option>
    <option value="Model 2">Model 2</option>
    <option value="Model 3">Model 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Without submitting? You have to use something like AJAX.

Comment: @putvande i say that is can be done with jQuery and I started putting together what i've picked up so far from the net. this is an example of what I found http://jsfiddle.net/fuDBL/

Comment: You can put the form data in a cookie or localStorage, then retrieve it on the next page.

Comment: You can't put it into PHP session variables directly. PHP runs on the server, Javascript runs on the client, and the only way to get data from one to the other is via submitting the form or using AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar you're right a cookie could work. how would I capture the values with jquery and then pass to a cookie?

Comment: If you use the jQuery Cookie Plugin, I believe it will automatically serialize objects that you put in the cookie. So put the data you want in an object and then set the cookie with the plugin.